# eclipse: is there a way to disable double click function on the tab?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: 3.0.2. By default, if I double click the tab, the editor will switch between normal view(has perspectives) and full screen view(has no perspectives), sometimes it is quite annoying when it keeps switching between two views. I want to have normal view(has perspectives), I do not want the full screen view, is there a way that I can disable double click function on the tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what can help you - http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-23.htm&resultof=%22windows%22%20%22window%22%20

PS: useful only if you are using Indigo.

Comment: It's not enough to just copy URL's without any explanation, try to add some description "why and how"... Without offense, this is just reminder

Comment: But all that needs to be explained is there in the link. (:

Comment: I don't see anything on this help page about disabling the double-click functionality